# setup mysql node on aws ec2 ubuntu

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2

I am running a node app with mysql as my database(xampp mysql). Whenever I run the "app.js" file with[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTvEn.jpg)

i get an error of code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3306,
fatal: true }

Comment: Connection refused means that either there is no mysql running there at all, or it listens on another port (or uses sockets) or something blocks the connection. We can"t tell from the error messagè which is the case here.

Comment: mysql is working fine and i know on which port is running.but is there any possible way for me to know if something blocks the connection